# Mailchimp signup success fade/hide

Tags: javascript, mailchimp

I am using a mailchimp email sign up on my site & am wondering if there is a simple way to fade the 'wait for your confirmation' div after 5 seconds so it doesn't just sit there or requires the user to click to another page to remove it?

Any help would be great.

The js code is below:

```
var fnames = new Array();
var ftypes = new Array();
fnames[0] = 'EMAIL';
ftypes[0] = 'email';
fnames[1] = 'FNAME';
ftypes[1] = 'text';
fnames[2] = 'LNAME';
ftypes[2] = 'text';
var err_style = '';
try {
    err_style = mc_custom_error_style;
} catch (e) {
    err_style = '';
}
var mce_jQuery = jQuery.noConflict();
mce_jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    var options = {
        errorElement: 'div',
        errorStyle: err_style,
        onkeyup: function () {},
        onfocusout: function () {},
        onblur: function () {}
    };
    var mce_validator = mce_jQuery("#mc-embedded-subscribe-form").validate(options);
    options = {
        url: 'http://wordpress.us2.list-manage.com/subscribe/post-json?u=d758d569eedf27b4c753c5997&id=62def7407f&c=?',
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        beforeSubmit: function () {
            mce_jQuery('#mce_tmp_error_msg').remove();
            mce_jQuery('.datefield', '#mc_embed_signup').each(function () {
                var txt = 'filled';
                var fields = new Array();
                var i = 0;
                mce_jQuery(':text', this).each(function () {
                    fields[i] = this;
                    i++;
                });
                mce_jQuery(':hidden', this).each(function () {
                    if (fields[0].value == 'MM' && fields[1].value == 'DD' && fields[2].value == 'YYYY') {
                        this.value = '';
                    } else if (fields[0].value == '' && fields[1].value == '' && fields[2].value == '') {
                        this.value = '';
                    } else {
                        this.value = fields[0].value + '/' + fields[1].value + '/' + fields[2].value;
                    }
                });
            });
            return mce_validator.form();
        },
        success: mce_success_cb
    };
    mce_jQuery('#mc-embedded-subscribe-form').ajaxForm(options);
});

function mce_success_cb(resp) {
    mce_jQuery('#mce-success-response').hide();
    mce_jQuery('#mce-error-response').hide();
    if (resp.result == "success") {
        mce_jQuery('#mce-' + resp.result + '-response').show();
        mce_jQuery('#mce-' + resp.result + '-response').html(resp.msg);
        mce_jQuery('#mc-embedded-subscribe-form').each(function () {
            this.reset();
        });
    } else {
        var index = -1;
        var msg;
        try {
            var parts = resp.msg.split(' - ', 2);
            if (parts[1] == undefined) {
                msg = resp.msg;
            } else {
                i = parseInt(parts[0]);
                if (i.toString() == parts[0]) {
                    index = parts[0];
                    msg = parts[1];
                } else {
                    index = -1;
                    msg = resp.msg;
                }
            }
        } catch (e) {
            index = -1;
            msg = resp.msg;
        }
        try {
            if (index == -1) {
                mce_jQuery('#mce-' + resp.result + '-response').show();
                mce_jQuery('#mce-' + resp.result + '-response').html(msg);
            } else {
                err_id = 'mce_tmp_error_msg';
                html = '<div id="' + err_id + '" style="' + err_style + '"> ' + msg + '</div>';
                var input_id = '#mc_embed_signup';
                var f = mce_jQuery(input_id);
                if (ftypes[index] == 'address') {
                    input_id = '#mce-' + fnames[index] + '-addr1';
                    f = mce_jQuery(input_id).parent().parent().get(0);
                } else if (ftypes[index] == 'date') {
                    input_id = '#mce-' + fnames[index] + '-month';
                    f = mce_jQuery(input_id).parent().parent().get(0);
                } else {
                    input_id = '#mce-' + fnames[index];
                    f = mce_jQuery().parent(input_id).get(0);
                }
                if (f) {
                    mce_jQuery(f).append(html);
                    mce_jQuery(input_id).focus();
                } else {
                    mce_jQuery('#mce-' + resp.result + '-response').show();
                    mce_jQuery('#mce-' + resp.result + '-response').html(msg);
                }
            }
        } catch (e) {
            mce_jQuery('#mce-' + resp.result + '-response').show();
            mce_jQuery('#mce-' + resp.result + '-response').html(msg);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The javascript setTimeout function will execute your code after a set period of time (in milliseconds). This is generally what you're looking for...

setTimeout("$("#id_of_div").fadeOut();", 5000);

Here's a link to the jQuery API fadeOut function.

http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/

Comment: That would seem to do the trick, I just have no idea where or how to correctly include it in the above code.

Comment: I don't know enough about the mailchimp API to know what's going on here. I would start in the "function mce_success_cb(resp)" function and start adding alert messages to find the place where the "wait for confirmation" div is activated. I see a few jQuery statements that are updating the DOM. .append(), .show(), and .html() are all changing the appearance of the page in some way. Throw some alert messages ( alert("test message");  )in there to see when they execute. When you find the point where you want to start the 5 second timer, insert the setTimeout code there.